# Is "I am mistaken?" right?

Tags: word-usage

Can a personal pronoun such as *I* and *they* be used in passive expressions of *mistake*?
If yes, what is the meaning?

For example,

> I am mistaken.
>   They are mistaken.

Comment: Don't forget subject-auxiliary inversion: **Is "Am I mistaken?" right?**

Answer (score 5):

Yes, those are correct.  If you had thought that they were wrong, you were mistaken.  QED.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. perfect example!. I got a more explanation in another question title, "Mistaking versus mistaken" where they say that mistaken is adjective but not passive verb.

Answer (score 1):

First, such question is known as a *declarative question* where the question in this context does not start with *am*, *is*. etc. (Ex- *She's your girlfriend?*).

Now the questions -

> *I am mistaken?; They are mistaken?* - these questions are correct.

The word *mistaken* is used as an adjective meaning wrong in opinion or judgement

> [mistaken (adj)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/MISTAKEN) - Wrong in e.g. opinion or judgment

If you use *mistaking*, it'll be the usage of *noun*.

> [mistaking (n)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=mistaking) - Putting the wrong interpretation on

Check out the examples there for the word usage.